# Strange error regarding Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by when there is no white space PHP

Tags: php, export-to-csv

I am trying to download CSV file using Header function but due to some reasons it is not downloading in browser.

Error is:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /xxx/fruitapp/report-admin/common/header.php:156) in /xxx/fruitapp/report-admin/pages/createCSVdamage.php on line 434
```

My `header.php file line 156` which error refers to have error is look like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
<?php if($title[0] != 'reports' && $title[0] != 'damage_reports' && $title[0] != 'Byconsignee_reports' && $title[0] != 'Byhold_reports' && $title[0] != 'general_reports'){?>
<div class="span3" id="sidebar">
  <ul class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav nav-collapse collapse">
    <?php if($title[0]=='dashboard'){?>
    <li class="active"><a href="index.php?select=dashboard"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>Dashboard</a></li>
    <?php }if($title[0]=='report_entry' || $title[0]=='add_report_entry' || $title[0]=='edit_report_entry'){?>
    <li><a href="index.php?select=report_entry"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>Manage Report Entry</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?select=add_report_entry"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>Add Report Entry</a></li>
    <?php }if($title[0]=='damage_entry' || $title[0]=='add_damage_entry' || $title[0]=='edit_damage_entry'){?>
    <li><a href="index.php?select=damage_entry"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>Manage Damage Entry</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?select=add_damage_entry"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>Add Damage Entry</a></li>
    <?php }if($title[0]=='edit'){?>
    <li><a href="index.php?select=edit"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>Manage Edit</a></li>
    <?php }if($title[0]=='search'){?>
    <li><a href="index.php?select=search"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>Manage Search</a></li>
    <?php }if($title[0]=='users' || $title[0]=='add_user' || $title[0]=='edit_user'){?>
    <li><a href="index.php?select=users"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>Manage User</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?select=add_user"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>Add Users</a></li>
    <?php }?>
  </ul>
</div>
<?php }?>
```

Apprently there is no white space in or even I tried using BOM as well but nothing is working.

Moreover, If i adds `ob_start();` it only export empty file when the file on ftp is full of data.

Code that is present in the end of my file is - I am using this code to download it in browser.

```
if ((isset($_REQUEST['date_from']) && $_REQUEST['date_from'] != "") || (isset($_REQUEST['date_to']) && $_REQUEST['date_to'] != "")) {
    fputcsv($file, array(
        'Report Number',
        'Consignee',
        'Pallet ID',
        'Label/Mark',
        'Fruit/Variety',
        'Deck',
        'Type',
        'Damage Description',
        'Pieces Damage',
        'Category'
    ));
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM damage") or die('Error In Query');
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) {
        $sqaal = mysql_query("SELECT
                                                    damage_entry.report_ID,
                                                    damage_entry.consignee,
                                                    damage_entry.pallet_ID,
                                                    damage_entry.label,
                                                    damage_entry.variety,
                                                    CONCAT(damage_entry.hold,damage_entry.deck),
                                                    damage_entry.type,
                                                    damage_entry.damage_desc,
                                                    damage_entry.pieces,
                                                    damage_entry.category_code
                                                FROM
                                                    damage_entry
                                                WHERE
                                                    damage='" . $rows->damage_name . "'  " . $cond . "") or die(mysqli_error(self::get_Conn()));
        $a = mysql_num_rows($sqaal);
        if ($a > 0) {
            fwrite($file, $rows->damage_name);
            fwrite($file, "\r\n");
            $valuesArray = array();
            $as          = 0;
            $sd          = array();
            $gggg        = array();
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqaal)) {
                $array = array(
                    $row['report_ID'],
                    $row['consignee'],
                    $row['pallet_ID'],
                    $row['label'],
                    $row['variety'],
                    $row['CONCAT(damage_entry.hold,damage_entry.deck)'],
                    $row['type'],
                    $row['damage_desc'],
                    $row['pieces'],
                    //$objadminViewFunctions->getCategoryLetter($row['category_code'])
                );
                array_push($sd, $row['pieces']);
                array_push($gggg, $row['pallet_ID']);
                fputcsv($file, $array);
            }
            fwrite($file, "\r\n");
            fputcsv($file, array(
                "",
                "Sub Total",
                count($gggg),
                "",
                "",
                "",
                "",
                "",
                array_sum($sd),
                "",
                ""
            ));
            fwrite($file, "\r\n");
        }
    }
} else {
    fputcsv($file, array(
            'Report Number',
            'Consignee',
            'Pallet ID',
            'Label/Mark',
            'Fruit/Variety',
            'Deck',
            'Type',
            'Damage Description',
            'Pieces Damage',
            'Category'
        ));
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM damage") or die('Error In Query');
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) {
        $sqaal = mysql_query("SELECT
                                                    damage_entry.de_ID,
                                                    damage_entry.report_ID,
                                                    damage_entry.consignee,
                                                    damage_entry.pallet_ID,
                                                    damage_entry.label,
                                                    damage_entry.variety,
                                                    CONCAT(damage_entry.hold,damage_entry.deck),
                                                    damage_entry.type,
                                                    damage_entry.damage_desc,
                                                    damage_entry.pieces,
                                                    damage_entry.category_code
                                                FROM
                                                    damage_entry
                                                WHERE
                                                    damage='" . $rows->damage_name . "'") or die(mysqli_error(self::get_Conn()));
        $a = mysql_num_rows($sqaal);
        if ($a > 0) {
            fwrite($file, $rows->damage_name);
            fwrite($file, "\r\n");
            $valuesArray = array();
            $as          = 0;
            $sd          = array();
            $gggg        = array();
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqaal)) {
                $array = array(
                    $row['report_ID'],
                    $row['consignee'],
                    $row['pallet_ID'],
                    $row['label'],
                    $row['variety'],
                    $row['CONCAT(damage_entry.hold,damage_entry.deck)'],
                    $row['type'],
                    $row['damage_desc'],
                    $row['pieces'],
                    //$objadminViewFunctions->getCategoryLetter($row['category_code'])
                );
                array_push($sd, $row['pieces']);
                array_push($gggg, $row['pallet_ID']);
                fputcsv($file, $array);
            }
            fwrite($file, "\r\n");
            fputcsv($file, array(
                "",
                "Sub Total",
                count($gggg),
                "",
                "",
                "",
                "",
                "",
                array_sum($sd),
                "",
                ""
            ));
            fwrite($file, "\r\n");
        }
    }
}
fclose($file);
$filename = $FileName;
if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
$file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($filename,"."),1));
switch( $file_extension ){
    case "pdf": $ctype="application/pdf"; break;
    case "exe": $ctype="application/octet-stream"; break;
    case "zip": $ctype="application/zip"; break;
    case "doc": $ctype="application/msword"; break;
    case "xls": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break;
    case "csv": $ctype="text/csv"; break;
    case "ppt": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break;
    case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
    case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
    case "jpeg":
    case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
    default: $ctype="application/force-download";
}
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
header("Content-Type: $ctype");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($filename)."\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
```

P.S: I have also used hex editor to check for BOM in my code but all code is clean and cleared. Nothing is outputting in header nor it is case in my question as it was not related to `echo` statement before `header` function.

My problem is that it is not downloading in browser.

Comment: Where do you send your headers?

Comment: just in the end of file when my CSV file gets ready.

Comment: Show line 156, and line 434 of other file

Comment: Thats the code you should show. :)

Comment: @Steve: line 156 is: `<?php if($title[0] != 'reports' && $title[0] != 'damage_reports' && $title[0] != 'Byconsignee_reports' && $title[0] != 'Byhold_reports' && $title[0] != 'general_reports'){?>`

Comment: @Steve these lines are: `header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
header("Content-Type: $ctype");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($filename)."\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: Right, well header.php clearly sends output - it is full of html! You cant send ANYTHING to the browser before setting headers

Comment: No my error is different. I have treid all the possible ways to solved this so far..

Comment: @Steve what can be a ideal fix?

Comment: Dont call header.php at all - you donty want html in your csv file. Just call createCSVdamage.php directly

Comment: @Steve let me give it a try. I can hope that can solve my problem.

Comment: @Steve: It did work for downloading only but now it is exporting empty csv file. Now?

Comment: Well i dont see any code to actually read the csv file to the output stream?  How are you doing that?

Comment: Save file with encoding `UTF-8 w/out BOM`

Comment: @DarkBee I did this too using `Notepad++` but dint work for me.

Comment: @Steve the file is creating proper csv file on ftp but content is missing in the file when exported to browser. Means no data and empty file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial problem is that you are somehow calling `header.php`, which contains a bunch of html - **NO** output of any kind can be sent to the browser before the headers.
The solution to that is to just call `createCSVdamage.php` directly.

Regarding your empty csv, you never actually send the csv data to the oputput stream. You can do that via [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) function after you set headers:

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
header("Content-Type: $ctype");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($filename)."\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));

//send the data to the browser
readfile($filename);
```

To move the file you can use the [rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)  and [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) functions after sendingh the data:

```
$fileData = pathinfo($filename);
$nameWithoutDirectory = $fileData['basename'];

rename($filename, 'some/directory/' . $nameWithoutDirectory);
```

Or alternatively just create the file in the correct directory in the first place!

Comment: Perfect Solution and matchless response to answer. :) Glad it solved my problem.

Comment: One more question: how I can move the file in separate directory instead of same directory after download in the browser?

Comment: Thank you very much for your great help and solutions. :)